# Converting an image in pygame to an 2D array of RGB values

Tags: python, pygame, rgb

How can I convert a surface object in pygame to a 2-dimensional array of RGB values (one value for every pixel)? I have read the documentation on PixelArrays and Surfarrays and I cannot seem to find an answer to my question. Examples are more than welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pygame [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) says that given a surface object, you can create a `PixelArray` wrapper to provide direct 2D array access to its pixels by calling the module's `PixelArray()` method like this:

```
pxarray = pygame.PixelArray(surface)
```

*Logically* a `PixelArray` object is a 2-dimensional array of RGB values stored as integers.

> A `PixelArray` pixel item can be assigned a raw integer value, a
>   `pygame.Color` instance (an object for color representations), or a `(r, g, b[, a])` tuple.
>
> ```
> pxarray[x, y] = 0xFF00FF
> pxarray[x, y] = pygame.Color(255, 0, 255)
> pxarray[x, y] = (255, 0, 255)
> ```

It also mentions:

> However, only a pixel’s integer value is returned. So, to compare a pixel to a
>   particular color, the color needs to be first mapped using the [`Surface.map_rgb()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.map_rgb)
>   method of the `Surface` object for which the `PixelArray` was created.

Which means you'll need to use the `Surface.map_rgb()` method to get RGB tuples from `PixelArray` integer values whenever you're not doing an assignment to the array, i.e. when *reading* a pixel's value, as is being done in the following conditional:

> `# Check, if the first pixel at the topleft corner is blue`
>      `if pxarray[0, 0] == surface.map_rgb((0, 0, 255)):`
>          `...`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

After wrapping a Surface in a [PixelArray](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html), the [unmap_rgb](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.unmap_rgb) function can convert the pixels into [pygame.Color](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html) objects.

For example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
image = pygame.image.load('example.png')
pixel = pygame.PixelArray(image)
center = int(image.get_width()/2), int(image.get_height()/2)
colour = image.unmap_rgb(pixel[center])
print(str(colour))
```

Edit: To do the complete conversion of all these pygame.Color objects into a two-dimensional array of RGB tuples, you could use this code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
image = pygame.image.load('example.png')
pixel = pygame.PixelArray(image)

color_array = [[image.unmap_rgb(pixel[x, y]) for x in range(0, image.get_width())] for y in range(0, image.get_height())]

rgb_array = [[(column.r, column.g, column.b) for column in row] for row in color_array]

print(str(rgb_array))
```

Note that if you were to use map_rgb (as suggested in the other answer), you might have to test every pixel against over 16 million map_rgb calls (one for each of 256 * 256 * 256 possible RGB values). If you wanted the alpha values as well, that would add another multiplication of possible values by 256. Another strategy using map_rgb might be to create a lookup table from the (256 ** n) possible values, and check each pixel against the table. While it is possible to do that, the code presented here seems much more efficient.